# How do I create a report based on String in Java?

Tags: java, string, file

Let's assume that I have a java program that creates a report by multiple threads writing .to a file:

```
public File report = new File("C:\somewhere\file")
public FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\somewhere\file");

//Some thread executed the following statement
fileWriter.write("creating report for this thread");
```

Instead of using a file, I want to use some type of String buffer to create the report so I can return it in a rest response. What can I use that has the same outcome as if using a File.

Update: I want to completely omit the file implementation as I can't store it in cloud.

Comment: If you are only writing strings to it, you could use the `Appendable` interface. Both `FileWriter` and `StringBuffer` implement it. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Appendable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `outputstream` of the `HttpServletResponse` to send the file as stream. Don't forget to make your header relevant. You can write a method to process the output as file:

```
public static void writeFileToOutputStream(HttpServletResponse response, File file) {
    String type = "application/octet-stream";
    response.setContentType(type);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline;filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""));
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("------couldn't write file------");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you do it without using files at all?. I can't store files in the cloud.

Comment: You can create the file as a temporary file and delete it just after writing it into the response stream.

Comment: I don't think the cloud allows to store it temporarily in the file system. Are you talking about creating a file in memory?

Comment: Well, yes, I was talking about in memory temporary file generation, where the code runs. But if you really want to avoid this file involving, you should use `StringBuffer`, and it will give you a single large `string`. But I highly doubt whether you can maintain formatting in the report with this.

Answer (score 0):

Several threads writing to the same would have one obvious solution: use `java.util.logging`. Writing to a log file. The content of a log file can also easily be returned as a REST response.

Using a string buffer, `StringBuilder` is faster, but not thread-safe. The older `StringBuffer` is thread-safe but not with twice appending, like in:

```
sb.append("The size is ").append(size); // Not thread-safe.
```

You could do:

```
private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);

public void printf(String messageFormat, Object... args) {
    String s = new MessageFormat(....);
    synchronized(sb) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
}

public String extract() {
    String s;
    synchronized(sb) {
        s = sb.toString();
        sb.setLength(0);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay implementation agnostic then you should design to an interface.  I'd suggest just plain old Writer.  You could have something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractReportWriter {
     protected Writer writer;

     public AbstractWriter(Writer w) {
         writer = w;
     }

     public void write(String text) {
        writer.write(text);
     }
}

public class FileReportWriter extends AbstractReportWriter {
    public FileReportWriter(String path) {
        super(new FileWriter(path))
    }
}

public class StringReportWriter extends AbstractReportWriter {
    public StringReportWriter() {
       super(new StringWriter())
    }

    public String getValue() {
       return ((StringWriter) writer).toString()
    }
}

public class CloudReportWriter extends AbstractReportWriter {
     public CloudReportWriter() {
         super(new YourCloudWriterClass());
     }
}
```

Then you can pick and choose your writer by just swapping the implementation.